# How to do negate or subtract a regex from another regex result in just one line of regex

Tags: swift, regex, xcode, subtraction, negate

I am trying to do a regex string to find all cases of force unwrapping in swift. This will search all words with exclamation points in the entire code base. However, the regex that I already have has included implicit declaration of variable which I am trying to exclude.

This is the regex that I already have.

```
(:\s)?\w+(?<!as)\)*!
```

And it works fine. It searches for "variableName!", "(variableName)!", "hello.hello!". The exclusion of force casting also works. It avoids cases like "hello as! UIView", But I am trying also to exclude another cases such as "var hello: UIView!" which has an exclamation point. That's the problem I am having. I tried negative lookahead and negative lookbehind and nothing solved this kind of case.

This is the sample regex I am working on

```
(:\s)?\w+(?<!as)\)*!
```

And this is the result

```
testing.(**test)))!**

Details lists capture **groups!**

hello as! hello

**Hello!**

**testing!**

testing**.test!**

Hello != World

var noNetworkBanner**: StatusBarNotificationBanner!** <-- need to exclude

"var noNetworkBanner**: StatusBarNotificationBanner!**" <-- need to exclude
```

Comment: Try `(?<!:\s)\b\w+(?<!\bas)\b\)*!`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThvgDJ/1).

Comment: Nice it works! Thank you. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!:\s)\b\w+(?<!\bas)\b\)*!
```

I added `\b` word boundaries to match whole words only, and changed the `(:\s)?` optional group to a negative lookbehind, `(?<!:\s)`, that disallows a `:` + space before the word you need to match.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThvgDJ/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!:\s)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a `:` and a whitespace
- `\b` - word boundary
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?<!\bas)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a whole word `as`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `\)*` - 0 or more `)` chars
- `!` - a `!` char.